# Proof for the convergence of $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x - x^2}}$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, definite-integrals

Consider the integral
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x - x^2}}$$

I know it does converge because I calculated it and the result is $\pi$. (It's sufficient to substitute $x = \sin^2(\theta)$).

I thought about:

$$\sqrt{x-x^2} \geq \sqrt{x} \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-x^2}} \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$$

Whence the integral converges because $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x$ converges.

Can you please tell me if/where I'm wrong, or suggest some more efficient techniques?

Thank you!

**EDIT** Thoughts on the asymptotics.

I can write around $x = 0$

$$(x-x^2)^{-1/2} = (1 + (x-x^2-1))^{-1/2} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\frac{3 x^{3/2}}{8}+O\left(x^{5/2}\right)$$

Hence

$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{\text{d}x}{\sqrt{x-x^2}} = \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{\sqrt{x}}{2}+\frac{3 x^{3/2}}{8}+O\left(x^{5/2}\right)$$

Showing there are no problems.

Is this valid too?

Comment: You can use the comparison test, but you should look at your inequality again.

Comment: @podiki Why? When $x\in (0, 1)$ we have $x^2 < x$

Comment: $x-x^2$ is not bigger than $x$ regardless of how $x$ and $x^2$ compare to each other. You have subtracted a positive number.

Comment: @podiki Ah gosh! I didn't notice! Then yes $x -x^2 \leq x$ but in this case the inequality is reversed and it does tell me nothing about the integral...

Comment: You can also note that $\sqrt{x-x^2}=\sqrt{x}\sqrt{1–x}$ so the divergence at 0 and 1 are both square root, hence integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your asymptotics cannot possibly be right, since $(x-x^2)^{-1/2}$ blows up at zero. And your inequality is written the wrong way, so it is not useful.

What you could do is to notice that since $x>0$,  if $x<\frac12$, then $x^2<\frac x 2$. So $x-x^2>x-\frac  x 2$ if $x<\frac12$. This gives you
$$
\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{\sqrt{x-x^2}}\leq\sqrt2\int_0^{1/2}\frac1{\sqrt x}<\infty.
$$
At the other end of the integral, you could notice that
$$
x-x^2=(1-x)-(1-x)^2,
$$
so the same estimate applies.

Comment: Whoops yes I blew up the asymptotics. The first term is indeed $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ which blows at $x = 0$. Thanky you!!

Comment: Just a question: since the first term of my asymptotics is indeed $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$, couldn't I also say that the integral does converge in that part because

$$\int_0^{1/2} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x-x^2}} = \int_0^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} + \ldots\ dx$$

Comment: Yes, if the asymptotics are as you wrote after the edit. There should be a small interval where the error term is bounded, and that's all you need.